# Not able to resolve ClassNotFoundException for DispatcherServlet (on Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ant

here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd ">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here is my spring-dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd "> 
   <bean name="/hello-world.html" class="com.wiley.jfib.ch06.helloworld.service.HelloWorldService" /> 
</beans>
```

Now my problem is that when I build my project (with Ant), it works well, but when I deploy it, I gets the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)....
```

I use spring-framework-2.5.5.

And my sproject structer show like this:

- bin

  - com.wiley.jfib.ch06.helloworld.service
- src

  - com.wiley.jfib.ch06.helloworld.service
- web

  - WEB-INF

    - jsp

      - hello-world.jsp
    - lib

      - jstl.jar, spring-webmvc.jar, spring.jar, standard.jar
    - web.xml, spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
- build.xml

Why that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an excess ">" after  you can see it in the exception as well